# Killing a BPMN subprocess with an external throw event

Tags: bpmn

I have a usage issue I need some advice on.

I have a process with a main flow which loops, retrying a task every *n* hours until either a condition is met or a timeout is reached. So far so good.

There is a transactional sub process triggered to run in parallel to this main loop which, for as long as this main loop is active, carries out its own looping behaviour (every *x* days). This second loop should run for as long as the main loop continues, and be killed as soon as the main loop reaches one of its progression criteria.

The way I'd like to model it would be to use a message/signal throw event from the main flow after it has passed its progress criteria, with a corresponding catch message/signal as a boundary event on the sub process, which then triggers a sub process end/terminate event inside the boundaries of the sub process.

I've looked long and hard at resources and the standard, and I can't see any examples of people using boundary events in this way (as an input from outside the sub process, leading to an end event inside the sub process). Any idea if this is valid?

If not valid, anyone have a better method for having a main flow kill a sub process in this way?

Comment: maybe you could provide a link to a graphical BPMN representation of your process. It's hard to understand your existing process just from reading the text

Answer (score 0):

Main Process: Start, parallel gateway (fork), first branch contains subprocess 1, second branch contains subprocess 2, exclusive gateway (join), end.

Subprocess 1: Start, loop, exit from the loop under some condition, then end.

Subprocess 2: Start, loop, no end node.

This way, subprocess 2 can't cause an end of looping of its own. But subprocess 1 can end, and by the exclusive join gateway, subprocess 2 will end as well.

I'm not quite sure whether a parallel fork, followed by an exclusive join, is actually allowed formally in BPMN. But some tools can handle it, and I received this hint from a tool vendor (Bonita).